# React-navigation error when trying to set up after installing - Element type is invalid

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am new to react-native was fiddling around and came across need of navigation. However, after following directions on reactnavigation.org my emulator is spewing out a nonsensical error to me. Google had no help sadly this time.

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
>
> Check the render method of `AwakeInDevApp`.

Code is most simplistic example they have:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome',
  };
  render() {
    return <Text>Hello, Navigation!</Text>;
  }
}

const EProj = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('EProj', () => EProj);
```

Dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^20.0.0",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "^0.47.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11"
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you don't need `AppRegistry.registerComponent('EProj', () => EProj);` with Expo try simply exporting your module like this : `export default EProj`

Here is a [link](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/2177) to a similar problem